# How to set the parameters for GLOP for a DUAL_FEASIBLE case

Tags: linear-programming, or-tools

Now I have a linear programming model, I have tried to formulate this model with or-tools, and then solve it with the GLOP but failed.

After reaching the 15-minute time limit, the status of GLOP is reported as NOT_SOLVED and the log output is listed below. I would like to ask, during the GLOP solving process, if the Primal Objective and Dual Objective are already very close to each other, can the results be outputted by setting appropriate parameters?

````
Dual optimization phase, iteration # 7025615, objective = 8.254744303120898E+11 [check]
Dual optimization phase, iteration # 7025616, objective = 8.254744303120903E+11 [check]
Dual optimization phase, iteration # 7025617, objective = 8.254744303120898E+11 [check]
Current status: DUAL_FEASIBLE
Primal infeasibility (bounds) = 1.54972e-06
Primal residual |A.x - b| = 5.36442e-07
Dual infeasibility (reduced costs) = 0
Dual residual |c_B - y.B| = 7.10543e-15

Final unscaled solution:
Primal objective (before moving primal/dual values) = 8.254744303120898E+11
Dual objective (before moving primal/dual values) = 8.254744303120900E+11
Primal objective (after moving primal/dual values) = 8.254744303120898E+11
Max. rhs perturbation = 2.38419e-06
Max. cost perturbation = 6.82121e-13
Max. primal infeasibility = 6.66827e-07
Max. dual infeasibility = 0
Objective error <= 825478
status: DUAL_FEASIBLE
objective: 8.25474e+11
iterations: 7025832
time: 900.001
deterministic_time: 1307.61

completed solve, status = NOT_SOLVED
```
````

Answer (score 1):

crossposted from https://groups.google.com/g/or-tools-discuss/c/hBZU_l_BqnI and answered there.

Comment: Thanks, I will try according to your instructions. I didn't know before that this forum is active.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" com.google.ortools.modelbuilder.ModelSolver$ModelSolverException: ModelSolver.getObjectiveValue(): solve() was not called or no solution was found

Comment: of course, a solution was not found.

Comment: So in this situation, it is unable to access the solutions data if the status is just DUAL_FEASIBLE?

Comment: I am not the expert at all. But I would expect that a *solution* needs to be primal feasible.